# Strange dashed line in pandas bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I can't find an explanation to (or a way of overriding) the dashed line in x:

```
DataFrame([1]).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Strange dotted line]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is just a base line indicate `y==0`, you can turn it off by: `ax.lines[0].set_visible(False)`:

```
ax = DataFrame([1]).plot(kind='bar')
ax.lines[0].set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylim(-0.2, 1.2)
```